# PHP: variable name as class instance

Tags: php, static-methods, instantiation, php-5.2

Im having a problem with using a variable as the class name when calling a static function within the class. My code is as follows:

```
class test {
     static function getInstance() {
         return new test();
     }
}

$className = "test";
$test = $className::getInstance();
```

Ive got to define the class name to a variable as the name of the class is coming from a database so i never know what class to create an instance of.

note: currently i am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

Thanks

Comment: Funnily enough, your code works for me in PHP 5.3.1 and does not throw an error.

Comment: variable static classes are available in PHP 5.3+, anything lower requires call_user_func() / call_user_func_array() as mentioned by @hobodave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$test = call_user_func(array($className, 'getInstance'));
```

See [call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func) and [callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Comment: Only way until 5.3 that is, in 5.3+ you can use variable classnames.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [reflection API](http://php.net/reflection), that would let you do something like:

```
$className = 'Test';
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($className);
$method = $reflector->getMethod('getInstance');
$instance = $method->invoke(null);
```

or even:

```
$className = 'Test';
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($className);
$instance = $reflector->newInstance(); 
// or $instance = $reflector->newInstanceArgs([array]);
// or $instance = $reflector->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
```

Both seem a lot cleaner to me than just interpreting the value of a string directly as a class name or using `call_user_func` and friends.